# Execution of nodetool command in Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, nosql

I'm trying to configure multiple nodes over a single node with Apache Cassandra, I created 3 nodes with those ip adress (127.0.0.2 & 127.0.0.3 & 127.0.0.4). The seed is 127.0.0.2.

Apparently when I lunch cassandra in every nodes, I don't have errors. But when I try to show nodes with nodetool command, this error is shown :

`nodetool -h 127.0.0.2 -p 8081 ring`

```
elyes@ubuntu:~/Cassandra/127.0.0.2/apache-cassandra-2.0.6$ bin/nodetool -h 127.0.0.2 -p 8081 ring
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/elyes/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.6/lib/pig-0.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/elyes/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.6/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$1.next(LinkedHashMultimap.java:508)
at com.google.common.collect.LinkedHashMultimap$1.next(LinkedHashMultimap.java:496)
at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
at java.util.Collections.max(Collections.java:735)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.printRing(NodeCmd.java:254)
at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:1214)
```

Any HELP please !! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a local cluster for development purposes is using [CCM](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm). I suggest you give it a try before installing Cassandra at multiple locations manually.